# Draw crosses in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

If I do

`\draw (1,1) circle (1pt)`

tikz draw a little circle with diameter `1pt` at `(1,1)`.

How can I define a path `cross` such that

`\draw (1,1) cross (1pt)`

draws a little cross with diameter `1pt` (adjustable in size just like the circle)?

Comment: if a `node` is OK, you can take a look ad http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15162/1952 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47281/1952. There is also a  `cross out` node in `shapes.misc` library (look at last example in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54856/1952).

Comment: @Ignasi you should turn your comment into an answer ;-)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`cross` command equivalent to `circle` doesn't exist in `TiKZ` but you can use a `cross out` node from `shapes.misc` library. This kind of node adds a cross over node's text, but it's easy to adapt it to do what you want.

```
\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw, 
         minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), 
         inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}
```

Because `circle (1pt)` draws a circle with radius=1pt, its total size will be 2pt, then `cross` node's size is defined with `minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth)` and `inner` and `outer` separations fixed to `0pt`.

If cross angle is not what you want, you can change it with `rotate` option. Next you have some examples. I've also placed `circles` over them just to show that circle and crosses  have equal size.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
%default radius will be 1pt. 
cross/.default={1pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\draw (0,0) circle (1pt);

\draw (.5,0) node[cross,rotate=10] {};
\draw (.5,0) circle (1pt);

\draw (0,.5) circle (1pt);
\draw (0,.5) node[cross,red] {};

\draw (.5,.5) node[cross,rotate=30] {};

\draw (0.25,.25) circle (2pt);
\draw (0.25,.25) node[cross=2pt,rotate=45,green]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Additional note: If somebody wanted a thicker cross, you could change that with the `line width` option.

Comment: Could you provide an example? My cross just disappears after specifying the line width

Comment: @Huhngut Make sure the `cross` size is larger than the `line width` or else it won't be visible. In practice, the `cross` size should probably be at least double the `line width` to resemble an actual cross.

Comment: e.g., `\draw (0.5, 0.25) node[cross=4pt, line width=2pt] {};`

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using `pic`:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\tikzset{
    cross/.pic = {
    \draw[rotate = 45] (-#1,0) -- (#1,0);
    \draw[rotate = 45] (0,-#1) -- (0, #1);
    }
}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw (0,0) circle (1pt);

    \path (.5,0) pic[rotate = 10] {cross=1pt};
    \draw (.5,0) circle (1pt);

    \draw (0,.5) circle (1pt);
    \path (0,.5) pic[red] {cross=1pt};

    \draw (.5,.5) pic[rotate = 30] {cross=1pt};

    \draw (0.25,.25) circle (2pt);
    \draw (0.25,.25) pic[rotate=45,green] {cross=2pt};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Notice that this solution always requires specification of the cross size. Is there anyone who knows how to modify this solution to add a default size?

Comment: You can use `\tikzset{pics/cross/.style args={#1}{code={...}}, pics/cross/.default=0.1}` for a cross with default size `0.1cm`. Substitute the `...` by the definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an "x" at the respective position:

```
\draw (1,1) node {x};
```

You can then adjust the size using font sizes like this:

```
\draw (1,1) node {\Huge x};
```

The center of the 'x' actually is placed exactly at the given coordinates.

Comment: too dependent on the font :(..

Comment: putting {$\times$} instead of {x} also gives quite a nice result