# Draw a cross symbol through arrow in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a cross symbol through the arrow in the tree below. I'm looking for something similar to the image attached below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
 \tikzset{every tree node/.style={baseline=(top.base),
level distance=2em, sibling distance=4em, align=center,
parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, anchor=north}, sibling distance=15pt}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}



  \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}  [inv/.style={overlay, coordinate  }, sibling distance=10pt] 
\Tree [.XP  \node(AA){X};               [.YP [.Y   ] [.ZP Z  \node(BB){X}; ]   ]]]]
  \draw[ ->  ] (AA.south)
.. controls +(south:5em)
 and +(south:2em) .. (BB.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some easy solutions:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
 \tikzset{every tree node/.style={baseline=(top.base),
level distance=2em, sibling distance=4em, align=center,
parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, anchor=north}, sibling distance=15pt}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations}



  \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}  [inv/.style={overlay, coordinate  }, sibling distance=10pt] 
\Tree [.XP  \node(AA){X};               [.YP [.Y   ] [.ZP Z  \node(BB){X}; ]   ]]]]
  \draw[ ->,red] (AA.south)
.. controls +(south:5em)
  and +(south:2em) .. (BB.south) node[pos=0.3,sloped]{\Large$X$};
    \draw[ -> ,blue] ([xshift=-15,yshift=-15]AA.south)
.. controls +(south:5em)
 and +(south:2em) .. ([xshift=-15,yshift=-15]BB.south) node[pos=0.3,sloped,rotate=45]{\Large$|$}node[pos=0.3,rotate=-65]{\Large$|$};
\end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Shifted just to demonstrate next to each other

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
 \tikzset{every tree node/.style={baseline=(top.base),
level distance=2em, sibling distance=4em, align=center,
parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, anchor=north}, sibling distance=15pt}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{pics/.cd,
    % Marque croix en diagonale
    Cross/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
        code = {%
        \draw[#2,rotate=45,scale=1.4,very thick]
                (0,#1 pt) -- (0,-#1 pt) ;
        \draw[#2,rotate=-45,scale=1.4,very thick]
                (0,#1 pt) -- (0,-#1 pt) ;
        }
    },
    Cross/.default={2.5 and gray!25!black}}


  \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}  [inv/.style={overlay, coordinate  }, sibling distance=10pt] 
\Tree [.XP  \node(AA){X};               [.YP [.Y   ] [.ZP Z  \node(BB){X}; ]   ]]]]
  \draw[ ->  ] (AA.south)
.. controls +(south:5em)
 and +(south:2em) .. (BB.south) pic[pos=.35,-,rotate=30] {Cross={4 and red}} ;



\end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

And yet another proposal, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124064/121799), mainly to say that Ignasi did this some time ago.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

   \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
 \tikzset{every tree node/.style={baseline=(top.base),
level distance=2em, sibling distance=4em, align=center,
parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, anchor=north}, sibling distance=15pt}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124064/121799
\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw, 
         minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), 
         inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}}


  \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}  [inv/.style={overlay, coordinate  }, sibling distance=10pt] 
\Tree [.XP  \node(AA){X};               [.YP [.Y   ] [.ZP Z  \node(BB){X}; ]   ]]]]
  \draw[ ->] (AA.south)
.. controls +(south:5em)
 and +(south:2em) .. (BB.south) node[pos=0.4,cross=5pt,sloped]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just to achieve your goal, without a very general (nor probably too elegant) approach, you could position a `node` along the path and then use it to draw your cross.

To position a node along the path, use something like

```
\draw[ ->  ] (AA.south) .. controls +(south:5em) and +(south:2em) .. (BB.south) node[pos=0.4] (M) {};
```

where the `pos` key moves the node along the path.

Once the node is placed, you can use something like

```
\draw (M.20) -- (M.200) (M.110) -- (M.290);
```

to put the cross on the path. `M.x`, where `x` is an angle in degree, denotes an anchor around the node. Connecting 180-degrees apart anchors starting with a 90-degrees shift (`x` to `x+180` and `x+90` to `x+270`), you obtain a cross on the path (because the center of the node is exactly on the path).

Have a look to section 17.8 *"Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly"* of the [`pgf` manual](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) and in general chapter 17 about nodes and edges to get inspired.

Comment: Instead of emty nodes we can always use '\coordinate'

Comment: @koleygr I agree, but a coordinate is just a point and, in my answer, the idea was to take advantage of the node `inner sep` in the following `\draw` command to draw the cross.

Comment: you are right... for a moment forgot the "pos" parameter there and thought you could name the point by a "coordinate" command. Anyway... already upvoted

Answer (score 5):

I have used, for example, `tikz-cd`. It is another way to resolve the question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{relsize, xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & XP \arrow[dash,ld] \arrow[dash,rd] &  &  &  \\
X \arrow[rrrrdd, bend right=49, "\textcolor{red}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\bigtimes}}}}" description] &  & YP \arrow[dash,ld] \arrow[dash,rd] &  &  \\
 & Y &  & ZP \arrow[dash,ld] \arrow[dash,rd] &  \\
 &  & Z &  & X
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```