# Enumerate item being moved to next page for unknown reason

Tags: xetex, page-breaking

Anyone can figure out why the part (c) in the solution part is compiled in the next page? How can I prevent this to happen? Thank you!

[image]

The following is my code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{times} %font: new times roman
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{mathtools} %for flalign
\usepackage{eqparbox} %for eqparbox

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math} %math font:XITS math

\pagenumbering{gobble} %no page no.

\usepackage[margin=50pt]{geometry} %set margin width

\setlength{\paperheight}{1200pt} %set page height

\usepackage{xcolor} %for colour

\setlength\parindent{0pt} %no paragraph indent

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

% From http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123760/draw-crosses-in-tikz
\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, fill=none, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}, cross/.default={2pt}}

\begin{document}

Figure 1 shows the graph of $\displaystyle y = 9 x^2 + 6mx - k+1 $, where $ m < 0$. The graph touches the $x$-axis at the point $P$, and it cuts the $y$-axis at the point $Q$.
\begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]
    \item Show that $ k = 1 - m^2 $. \hfill \textbf{(2 marks)}
    \item Find, in terms of $m$, the coordinates of $Q$ and $P$. \hfill \textbf{(3 marks)}
    \item Find the values of $m$ and $k$ if the area of $\Delta OPQ$ is $\displaystyle \frac{4}{3}$ square units.  \hfill \textbf{(2 marks)}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
        \begin{axis}[
            ticks=none,
            x=1cm,y=1cm,
            axis lines=middle,
            axis line style = very thick,
            xmin=-2,
            xmax=6,
            ymin=-1,
            ymax=7,
            x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north},
            y label style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=west},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$}] %axis style setting
            \addplot[samples = 200, domain={-1.6:5.6},line width=1pt] {0.5*(x-2)^2};
            \draw (0,2) node[left] {$Q$} -- (2,0) node[below] {$P$} ;
            \draw (0,0) node[anchor = north east] {$O$};
            \draw (2.5,5) node {$ y = 9 x^2 + 6mx - k+1   $};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
    \caption{Figure 1}
\end{figure}
    {
    \color{red}
    Solution:
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]
        \item
        \begin{flalign*}
            & & \Delta &  =  0 &\\
            & & (6m)^2 - 4(9)(-k+1) & = 0 & \eqparbox{C}{1M}\\
            & & m^2 + k - 1 &= 0 & \\
            & & k &= 1 - m^2 & \eqparbox{C}{1A}
        \end{flalign*}
        \item
        When $x = 0$, $ y= -k + 1 = -1+m^2 + 1 = m^2$.\\
        $\therefore$ $Q(0,m^2)$. \hfill 1A \\
        When $y = 0$,
        \begin{flalign*}
            & & 0 &= 9x^2 + 6mx + m^2 &\\
            & & 0 & = (3x + m)^2 & \eqparbox{C}{1M}\\
            & & x & = -\frac{m}{3} &
        \end{flalign*}
        $\therefore$ $\displaystyle P \left( -\frac{m}{3},0\right) $. \hfill 1A
        \item Area of $\Delta OPQ$ $\displaystyle = \frac{1}{2}(m^2)\left( -\frac{m}{3}  \right) = -\frac{m^3}{6}$ \hfill 1M
        \begin{flalign*}
        & & -\frac{m^3}{6} & =  \frac{4}{3} \\
        & & m & = - 2 &
        \end{flalign*}
        $k = 1- (- 2)^2 = -3 $ \hfill 1A
            \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mico I need to set the paper height to be a particular length for my project, so I have to include \setlength{\paperheight}{1200pt}. And even I deleted these, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Mico I want to get a pdf file which include everything in one page.

Comment: @Mico Yes, this solves my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to (a) delete the instruction `\setlength{\paperheight}{1200pt}` and (b) change `\usepackage[margin=50pt]{geometry}` to `\usepackage[paperheight=1200pt, margin=50pt]{geometry}`.

While you're at it, do also delete the instruction `\usepackage{times}`.