# Custom Tikz node with background graphics that scale to node size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, scaling

I have an SVG shape, which I'd like to use as a sort of a TikZ node border. The shape is basically a path with stroke effects - but the effects have been "baked in", so now I just have a non-stroked path as a final output; so in `inkscape` it looks like this:

[image: custombordershape_ink]

Thus, using it as a "proper" border will be difficult - so I'd like the next best thing: that is, for the "border image" to be drawn scaled to the size of a rectangular node.

The source SVG is here: [custombordershape.svg](https://cdn.mediacru.sh/dVx2oZ2Dx8gI.svg). Using the Tikz exporter in `inkscape`, I can export the same file to `tikz`, which has been pasted below as `custombordershape_tikz.tex`. (compiling it, I obtain `custombordershape_tikz.pdf`, which is used in the test code below).

At this time, I found two related questions:

- [tikz pgf - Creating node shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/creating-node-shapes)
- [graphics - Tikz: using external images as building blocks.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/tikz-using-external-images-as-building-blocks)

The first approach is much better - but I cannot afford the time to convert the path in the image to low-level pgf commands, so I'd settle for a scaled image. That leaves me with the approach in the second link, which among other things, recommends `\includegraphics`. So here is a small MWE, `test.tex`, which I've used to try that out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=red] (n1) at (1,0) {\pgftext{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{custombordershape_tikz.pdf}}Testing};
\node[draw=red,align=left,text width=250pt,minimum width=250pt] (n2) [right=5pt of n1] {\pgftext{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{custombordershape_tikz.pdf}}\lipsum[4]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image: test2.png]

I would have wanted the custombordershape to fit within the red bounding boxes of the respective nodes (and preferably, behind the text; should have made the color gray to check for that); however, clearly that is not how it turned out.

So, what would be the recommended way to achieve "custom nodes" (hopefully, eventually callable only through a tikz style) with external background graphics that scales to the size of the node?

Given that I also have the background shape in `tikz` path format, would there be an easier way to reuse that for a "custom" node definition, instead of using `\includegraphics` on the resulting pdf?

`custombordershape_tikz.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{scope}[shift={(-82.356111,-10.404272)}]% layer1
  % path3193
  \path[color=black,draw=black,fill=black,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.800pt]
    (88.3126,84.1662) .. controls (119.3839,59.7883) and (150.4194,35.4229) ..
    (181.4190,11.0699) .. controls (195.2747,11.0104) and (209.1177,10.9552) ..
    (222.9480,10.9043) .. controls (236.0262,11.3164) and (249.1067,12.0061) ..
    (262.1675,13.0685) .. controls (276.2273,14.2122) and (290.2969,15.7785) ..
    (304.2800,18.1188) .. controls (316.9975,20.2388) and (329.7769,22.9688) ..
    (342.1644,27.3079) .. controls (347.3201,29.1118) and (352.4536,31.2466) ..
    (357.3736,33.9560) .. controls (357.3736,33.9560) and (357.3736,33.9560) ..
    (357.3736,33.9560) .. controls (361.4740,36.1969) and (365.4940,38.9437) ..
    (368.9931,42.4708) .. controls (368.9931,42.4708) and (368.9931,42.4708) ..
    (368.9931,42.4708) .. controls (371.9776,45.4571) and (374.4607,49.1795) ..
    (375.8351,53.5099) .. controls (377.1521,57.9341) and (377.1035,62.5489) ..
    (375.9901,66.7999) .. controls (375.9901,66.7999) and (375.9901,66.7999) ..
    (375.9900,66.7999) .. controls (375.9900,66.7999) and (375.9900,66.8000) ..
    (375.9900,66.8000) .. controls (374.5540,72.2195) and (371.8596,76.9865) ..
    (368.7736,81.1359) .. controls (368.7736,81.1359) and (368.7736,81.1359) ..
    (368.7736,81.1360) .. controls (364.0149,85.8523) and (358.4752,89.7947) ..
    (352.7532,93.2987) .. controls (378.2527,92.4528) and (403.8614,88.7208) ..
    (428.3691,80.7837) .. controls (428.3691,80.7837) and (428.3691,80.7837) ..
    (428.3691,80.7837) .. controls (446.2121,75.8733) and (463.4729,68.7906) ..
    (479.2016,59.1792) .. controls (489.3775,52.9588) and (498.9333,45.7435) ..
    (507.2811,37.3486) .. controls (509.5718,35.0452) and (511.7600,32.6737) ..
    (513.7769,30.1940) .. controls (513.7769,30.1940) and (513.7769,30.1940) ..
    (513.7769,30.1939) .. controls (514.3092,29.5395) and (514.8227,28.8880) ..
    (515.3080,28.2333) .. controls (515.4330,28.0647) and (515.5526,27.9012) ..
    (515.6654,27.7420) .. controls (516.2398,27.4626) and (516.8118,27.1863) ..
    (517.3813,26.9128) .. controls (517.3814,26.9127) and (517.3816,26.9127) ..
    (517.3817,26.9126) .. controls (517.3819,26.9125) and (517.3820,26.9124) ..
    (517.3822,26.9124) .. controls (517.4610,26.8697) and (517.5397,26.8271) ..
    (517.6184,26.7845) .. controls (517.6186,26.7844) and (517.6187,26.7843) ..
    (517.6189,26.7842) .. controls (517.6460,26.7696) and (517.6730,26.7549) ..
    (517.7000,26.7402) .. controls (517.7001,26.7402) and (517.7001,26.7401) ..
    (517.7002,26.7401) .. controls (517.7384,26.7287) and (517.7721,26.7167) ..
    (517.8057,26.7046) .. controls (517.9091,26.6699) and (518.0124,26.6353) ..
    (518.1158,26.6006) .. controls (518.5242,26.4635) and (518.9322,26.3265) ..
    (519.3398,26.1896) .. controls (519.6205,26.2312) and (519.8993,26.2736) ..
    (520.1764,26.3161) .. controls (521.2465,26.4805) and (522.3122,26.6515) ..
    (523.3742,26.8262) .. controls (527.3249,27.4759) and (531.2608,28.1818) ..
    (535.1841,28.9255) .. controls (548.5481,31.4585) and (561.8256,34.4391) ..
    (574.9878,37.8572) .. controls (574.9878,37.8572) and (574.9878,37.8572) ..
    (574.9879,37.8572) .. controls (592.2183,42.3304) and (609.2859,47.5624) ..
    (625.9635,53.9084) .. controls (643.1553,60.4433) and (660.0491,68.1573) ..
    (675.6732,78.1250) .. controls (682.8865,82.7271) and (689.8284,87.8512) ..
    (696.1810,93.6946) .. controls (696.1811,93.6947) and (696.1811,93.6947) ..
    (696.1811,93.6947) .. controls (702.0214,99.0619) and (707.3627,105.0863) ..
    (711.6831,111.8630) .. controls (715.7596,118.2581) and (718.8414,125.3501) ..
    (720.4470,132.8385) .. controls (722.1070,140.6546) and (722.0962,148.7503) ..
    (720.6503,156.5438) .. controls (718.9193,165.8285) and (715.3263,174.6094) ..
    (710.7741,182.7058) .. controls (704.9045,193.1590) and (697.5142,202.6154) ..
    (689.5039,211.3539) .. controls (679.0292,222.7893) and (667.4380,233.0972) ..
    (655.3890,242.7212) .. controls (655.3890,242.7212) and (655.3890,242.7212) ..
    (655.3890,242.7212) .. controls (639.7589,255.1596) and (623.3180,266.4937) ..
    (606.5183,277.1699) .. controls (606.5183,277.1699) and (606.5183,277.1699) ..
    (606.5183,277.1699) .. controls (606.5182,277.1699) and (606.5182,277.1699) ..
    (606.5182,277.1699) .. controls (606.5182,277.1699) and (606.5182,277.1699) ..
    (606.5182,277.1699) .. controls (573.7686,284.1402) and (540.8445,290.4535) ..
    (507.6340,294.7866) .. controls (507.6339,294.7866) and (507.6339,294.7866) ..
    (507.6339,294.7866) .. controls (507.6339,294.7866) and (507.6339,294.7866) ..
    (507.6339,294.7866) .. controls (487.0405,297.4599) and (466.2315,299.5662) ..
    (445.3631,298.9541) .. controls (445.3631,298.9541) and (445.3631,298.9541) ..
    (445.3631,298.9541) .. controls (438.7497,298.7611) and (432.0972,298.2685) ..
    (425.5230,297.0775) .. controls (420.9242,296.2504) and (416.2952,295.0659) ..
    (411.9459,293.0484) .. controls (408.9251,291.6605) and (405.9970,289.7631) ..
    (403.7314,287.1009) .. controls (403.7314,287.1009) and (403.7314,287.1009) ..
    (403.7314,287.1009) .. controls (401.9395,284.9708) and (400.7335,282.3604) ..
    (400.3201,279.5879) .. controls (400.3201,279.5879) and (400.3201,279.5879) ..
    (400.3201,279.5878) .. controls (399.9247,276.7962) and (400.2646,274.0063) ..
    (401.0113,271.4170) .. controls (401.0113,271.4170) and (401.0113,271.4170) ..
    (401.0113,271.4169) .. controls (401.8492,268.4834) and (403.1397,265.7412) ..
    (404.6261,263.1742) .. controls (407.9354,257.4513) and (412.1752,252.3870) ..
    (416.6561,247.6813) .. controls (416.6561,247.6813) and (416.6562,247.6812) ..
    (416.6562,247.6812) .. controls (420.5929,243.5400) and (424.7782,239.6513) ..
    (429.1217,235.9664) .. controls (429.1217,235.9664) and (429.1217,235.9664) ..
    (429.1217,235.9664) .. controls (430.4943,234.8018) and (431.8855,233.6559) ..
    (433.2994,232.5356) .. controls (433.2994,232.5356) and (433.2995,232.5356) ..
    (433.2995,232.5356) .. controls (433.9627,232.5266) and (434.6253,232.5167) ..
    (435.2874,232.5047) .. controls (435.2924,232.5307) and (435.2981,232.5566) ..
    (435.3035,232.5826) .. controls (435.3191,232.6580) and (435.3347,232.7335) ..
    (435.3503,232.8090) .. controls (435.3503,232.8091) and (435.3503,232.8092) ..
    (435.3503,232.8093) .. controls (435.4119,233.1073) and (435.4734,233.4052) ..
    (435.5347,233.7031) .. controls (435.5347,233.7032) and (435.5347,233.7033) ..
    (435.5347,233.7034) .. controls (435.3842,233.7004) and (435.2333,233.6974) ..
    (435.0821,233.6944) .. controls (434.4957,233.6836) and (433.9088,233.6747) ..
    (433.3212,233.6669) .. controls (431.1133,233.6375) and (428.9042,233.6233) ..
    (426.6939,233.6190) .. controls (426.6939,233.6190) and (426.6939,233.6190) ..
    (426.6939,233.6190) .. controls (418.9800,233.6040) and (411.2649,233.7102) ..
    (403.5519,233.9247) .. controls (403.5519,233.9247) and (403.5519,233.9247) ..
    (403.5519,233.9247) .. controls (393.0416,234.2171) and (382.5382,234.7124) ..
    (372.0552,235.4762) .. controls (372.0552,235.4762) and (372.0552,235.4762) ..
    (372.0552,235.4762) .. controls (360.6610,236.3065) and (349.2917,237.4407) ..
    (338.0055,239.1229) .. controls (338.0055,239.1229) and (338.0055,239.1229) ..
    (338.0055,239.1229) .. controls (338.0054,239.1229) and (338.0054,239.1230) ..
    (338.0054,239.1230) .. controls (327.5978,240.6757) and (317.2477,242.6361) ..
    (307.2257,245.7016) .. controls (307.2257,245.7016) and (307.2257,245.7016) ..
    (307.2256,245.7016) .. controls (303.0114,246.9909) and (298.8644,248.4759) ..
    (294.8987,250.3345) .. controls (291.5892,251.8885) and (288.3991,253.6814) ..
    (285.6074,255.9566) .. controls (283.3329,257.8176) and (281.3089,259.9987) ..
    (280.0584,262.5680) .. controls (278.8967,264.9273) and (278.4530,267.6454) ..
    (278.7756,270.2662) .. controls (278.7756,270.2662) and (278.7756,270.2662) ..
    (278.7757,270.2663) .. controls (279.1629,273.5211) and (280.6149,276.6279) ..
    (282.4305,279.4783) .. controls (282.4305,279.4783) and (282.4305,279.4783) ..
    (282.4305,279.4783) .. controls (284.9396,283.7553) and (288.2219,287.5222) ..
    (291.7271,291.0324) .. controls (256.9666,294.8001) and (221.3088,293.1164) ..
    (188.1927,282.3136) .. controls (188.1927,282.3136) and (188.1926,282.3136) ..
    (188.1926,282.3136) .. controls (164.6618,274.5301) and (142.6438,262.0560) ..
    (124.3125,245.4118) .. controls (111.5478,233.8214) and (100.5184,220.3117) ..
    (91.8691,205.4131) .. controls (91.8691,205.4131) and (91.8691,205.4131) ..
    (91.8691,205.4131) .. controls (91.8691,205.4131) and (91.8691,205.4131) ..
    (91.8691,205.4131) .. controls (89.3190,201.0206) and (86.9709,196.5078) ..
    (84.9234,191.8606) .. controls (84.3653,190.5940) and (83.8294,189.3172) ..
    (83.3314,188.0256) .. controls (83.3314,188.0256) and (83.3314,188.0256) ..
    (83.3314,188.0256) .. controls (83.3314,188.0256) and (83.3314,188.0256) ..
    (83.3313,188.0256) .. controls (83.2013,187.6883) and (83.0738,187.3499) ..
    (82.9510,187.0097) .. controls (82.9247,186.9208) and (82.8986,186.8318) ..
    (82.8730,186.7426) .. controls (82.8690,186.7191) and (82.8650,186.6956) ..
    (82.8611,186.6721) .. controls (82.8601,186.6661) and (82.8591,186.6601) ..
    (82.8581,186.6542) .. controls (82.8564,186.6482) and (82.8567,186.6482) ..
    (82.8571,186.6482) .. controls (82.8568,186.6483) and (82.8564,186.6484) ..
    (82.8561,186.6485) .. controls (82.8591,186.6604) and (82.8601,186.6664) ..
    (82.8611,186.6723) .. controls (82.8651,186.6958) and (82.8691,186.7193) ..
    (82.8733,186.7428) .. controls (82.8733,186.7428) and (82.8733,186.7428) ..
    (82.8733,186.7428) .. controls (82.8992,186.8319) and (82.9259,186.9207) ..
    (82.9530,187.0093) .. controls (83.0778,187.3487) and (83.2073,187.6863) ..
    (83.3393,188.0228) .. controls (83.3394,188.0228) and (83.3394,188.0229) ..
    (83.3394,188.0229) .. controls (83.3394,188.0229) and (83.3394,188.0229) ..
    (83.3394,188.0229) .. controls (83.8450,189.3113) and (84.3883,190.5845) ..
    (84.9536,191.8475) .. controls (87.0279,196.4813) and (89.4013,200.9772) ..
    (91.9753,205.3514) .. controls (91.9753,205.3514) and (91.9753,205.3514) ..
    (91.9753,205.3514) .. controls (100.7056,220.1874) and (111.7982,233.6080) ..
    (124.5992,245.0945) .. controls (124.5992,245.0945) and (124.5992,245.0945) ..
    (124.5992,245.0945) .. controls (124.5992,245.0945) and (124.5992,245.0945) ..
    (124.5992,245.0945) .. controls (142.9800,261.5882) and (164.9952,273.8811) ..
    (188.4621,281.4913) .. controls (188.4621,281.4913) and (188.4621,281.4913) ..
    (188.4621,281.4913) .. controls (221.4094,292.3079) and (256.7636,294.1822) ..
    (291.1511,290.8420) .. controls (291.1511,290.8420) and (291.1511,290.8420) ..
    (291.1511,290.8420) .. controls (287.4379,287.7146) and (283.9099,284.2978) ..
    (281.1132,280.3287) .. controls (281.1132,280.3287) and (281.1132,280.3287) ..
    (281.1132,280.3287) .. controls (279.1856,277.3775) and (277.6334,274.0594) ..
    (277.1594,270.4701) .. controls (277.1594,270.4701) and (277.1594,270.4701) ..
    (277.1594,270.4700) .. controls (276.7826,267.5370) and (277.2593,264.5058) ..
    (278.5493,261.8332) .. controls (279.9442,258.9712) and (282.1059,256.5853) ..
    (284.5104,254.6164) .. controls (287.4450,252.2051) and (290.7464,250.3155) ..
    (294.1313,248.7091) .. controls (298.1886,246.7805) and (302.4079,245.2392) ..
    (306.6718,243.9092) .. controls (316.8073,240.7470) and (327.2427,238.7027) ..
    (337.6953,237.0836) .. controls (337.6953,237.0836) and (337.6953,237.0836) ..
    (337.6954,237.0836) .. controls (349.0375,235.3251) and (360.4545,234.1173) ..
    (371.8840,233.2172) .. controls (382.4008,232.3886) and (392.9365,231.8293) ..
    (403.4765,231.4739) .. controls (411.2110,231.2131) and (418.9504,231.0609) ..
    (426.6913,231.0302) .. controls (428.9093,231.0212) and (431.1284,231.0222) ..
    (433.3485,231.0392) .. controls (433.9393,231.0432) and (434.5308,231.0492) ..
    (435.1228,231.0565) .. controls (435.2755,231.0585) and (435.4285,231.0605) ..
    (435.5818,231.0625) .. controls (435.7170,231.3514) and (435.8523,231.6404) ..
    (435.9877,231.9295) .. controls (435.9878,231.9297) and (435.9879,231.9299) ..
    (435.9880,231.9301) .. controls (436.0222,232.0032) and (436.0565,232.0762) ..
    (436.0907,232.1493) .. controls (436.1024,232.1744) and (436.1142,232.1995) ..
    (436.1259,232.2245) .. controls (436.1260,232.2246) and (436.1260,232.2247) ..
    (436.1261,232.2248) .. controls (435.7314,233.0212) and (435.3373,233.8193) ..
    (434.9438,234.6191) .. controls (434.9438,234.6191) and (434.9438,234.6192) ..
    (434.9438,234.6192) .. controls (433.5660,235.7241) and (432.2080,236.8564) ..
    (430.8653,238.0094) .. controls (426.6053,241.6681) and (422.5135,245.5142) ..
    (418.6810,249.5949) .. controls (418.6810,249.5949) and (418.6810,249.5949) ..
    (418.6810,249.5949) .. controls (414.3160,254.2504) and (410.2383,259.1617) ..
    (407.1421,264.6163) .. controls (405.7579,267.0585) and (404.5756,269.5874) ..
    (403.8525,272.2146) .. controls (403.8525,272.2147) and (403.8525,272.2147) ..
    (403.8525,272.2147) .. controls (403.8525,272.2147) and (403.8525,272.2147) ..
    (403.8525,272.2147) .. controls (403.2241,274.5233) and (402.9260,276.9016) ..
    (403.2832,279.1449) .. controls (403.2832,279.1449) and (403.2832,279.1449) ..
    (403.2832,279.1450) .. controls (403.6122,281.3347) and (404.6065,283.4372) ..
    (406.0533,285.1383) .. controls (407.9018,287.3420) and (410.4877,288.9534) ..
    (413.2459,290.2380) .. controls (417.2474,292.0829) and (421.6264,293.1596) ..
    (426.0817,293.9490) .. controls (432.4402,295.0673) and (438.9334,295.5045) ..
    (445.4508,295.6611) .. controls (466.0349,296.1527) and (486.6415,293.9334) ..
    (507.1527,291.1570) .. controls (507.1527,291.1570) and (507.1527,291.1570) ..
    (507.1528,291.1570) .. controls (539.9917,286.7330) and (572.5370,280.3412) ..
    (604.9239,273.3024) .. controls (604.9239,273.3024) and (604.9239,273.3024) ..
    (604.9239,273.3024) .. controls (604.9239,273.3024) and (604.9239,273.3024) ..
    (604.9240,273.3024) .. controls (604.9240,273.3024) and (604.9240,273.3024) ..
    (604.9240,273.3024) .. controls (621.3553,262.6722) and (637.3694,251.4293) ..
    (652.5064,239.1354) .. controls (652.5064,239.1354) and (652.5064,239.1354) ..
    (652.5064,239.1354) .. controls (664.3691,229.5375) and (675.7227,219.3277) ..
    (685.9006,208.0741) .. controls (693.6794,199.4670) and (700.7929,190.2748) ..
    (706.3357,180.2343) .. controls (710.6193,172.4643) and (713.9719,164.1891) ..
    (715.4941,155.6052) .. controls (715.4941,155.6051) and (715.4941,155.6051) ..
    (715.4941,155.6051) .. controls (716.7728,148.4327) and (716.7475,141.0272) ..
    (715.1927,133.9746) .. controls (713.7146,127.2018) and (710.8371,120.7233) ..
    (707.0470,114.8312) .. controls (703.0181,108.5669) and (697.9529,102.9434) ..
    (692.3717,97.8565) .. controls (692.3717,97.8565) and (692.3717,97.8565) ..
    (692.3717,97.8565) .. controls (686.2924,92.3208) and (679.5873,87.4413) ..
    (672.5706,83.0148) .. controls (657.3562,73.4160) and (640.7835,65.9847) ..
    (623.8053,59.6292) .. controls (607.3448,53.4741) and (590.4662,48.4118) ..
    (573.3904,44.0834) .. controls (573.3904,44.0834) and (573.3904,44.0834) ..
    (573.3904,44.0834) .. controls (573.3903,44.0834) and (573.3903,44.0834) ..
    (573.3903,44.0834) .. controls (573.3903,44.0834) and (573.3903,44.0834) ..
    (573.3903,44.0834) .. controls (560.3464,40.7781) and (547.1938,37.9071) ..
    (533.9616,35.4799) .. controls (530.0770,34.7674) and (526.1906,34.0939) ..
    (522.3003,33.4778) .. controls (522.3003,33.4778) and (522.3003,33.4778) ..
    (522.3003,33.4778) .. controls (522.3003,33.4778) and (522.3003,33.4778) ..
    (522.3003,33.4778) .. controls (522.3003,33.4778) and (522.3003,33.4778) ..
    (522.3003,33.4778) .. controls (521.2545,33.3122) and (520.2112,33.1511) ..
    (519.1700,32.9974) .. controls (518.9003,32.9577) and (518.6323,32.9186) ..
    (518.3658,32.8806) .. controls (518.6320,32.7243) and (518.8986,32.5680) ..
    (519.1656,32.4119) .. controls (519.2331,32.3724) and (519.3007,32.3329) ..
    (519.3683,32.2934) .. controls (519.3928,32.2802) and (519.4174,32.2670) ..
    (519.4419,32.2538) .. controls (519.4379,32.2531) and (519.4379,32.2531) ..
    (519.4379,32.2530) .. controls (519.4592,32.2467) and (519.4805,32.2405) ..
    (519.5018,32.2342) .. controls (519.5636,32.2159) and (519.6253,32.1976) ..
    (519.6871,32.1792) .. controls (519.6872,32.1792) and (519.6873,32.1792) ..
    (519.6875,32.1791) .. controls (520.1883,32.0021) and (520.6910,31.8216) ..
    (521.1957,31.6380) .. controls (521.0476,31.8493) and (520.9010,32.0526) ..
    (520.7571,32.2489) .. controls (520.7571,32.2489) and (520.7570,32.2489) ..
    (520.7570,32.2489) .. controls (520.1981,33.0112) and (519.6265,33.7465) ..
    (519.0517,34.4607) .. controls (519.0517,34.4607) and (519.0517,34.4607) ..
    (519.0517,34.4608) .. controls (516.8727,37.1680) and (514.5477,39.7220) ..
    (512.1461,42.1616) .. controls (503.3887,51.0566) and (493.4424,58.6755) ..
    (482.8983,65.1925) .. controls (482.8983,65.1925) and (482.8983,65.1925) ..
    (482.8983,65.1925) .. controls (466.5823,75.2802) and (448.7475,82.7379) ..
    (430.3496,87.9053) .. controls (404.2711,94.0406) and (377.1130,95.7334) ..
    (350.1087,94.2811) .. controls (354.7073,88.6842) and (358.9805,82.8454) ..
    (362.3239,76.4397) .. controls (362.3240,76.4397) and (362.3240,76.4396) ..
    (362.3240,76.4396) .. controls (364.9737,72.7114) and (367.2125,68.8436) ..
    (368.1732,64.8166) .. controls (368.9028,61.8032) and (368.9645,58.6484) ..
    (368.0672,55.9121) .. controls (368.0672,55.9120) and (368.0672,55.9120) ..
    (368.0672,55.9120) .. controls (367.2438,53.1355) and (365.4058,50.5364) ..
    (363.1625,48.2319) .. controls (360.4463,45.4690) and (357.0448,43.2228) ..
    (353.3934,41.2110) .. controls (349.0061,38.8142) and (344.2840,36.8969) ..
    (339.4140,35.2122) .. controls (327.6849,31.1595) and (315.3633,28.6244) ..
    (302.8851,26.6001) .. controls (302.8851,26.6001) and (302.8850,26.6001) ..
    (302.8850,26.6001) .. controls (302.8850,26.6001) and (302.8850,26.6001) ..
    (302.8850,26.6001) .. controls (289.2010,24.3896) and (275.3678,22.9356) ..
    (261.4752,21.8849) .. controls (248.6103,20.9121) and (235.7094,20.3075) ..
    (222.7928,19.9756) .. controls (209.9469,19.7763) and (197.1140,19.5727) ..
    (184.2940,19.3648) .. controls (154.3411,43.5847) and (124.4246,67.7921) ..
    (94.5446,91.9868) -- cycle;

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is one way, using the `path picture` as in [TikZ Node with multiple shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47263/tikz-node-with-multiple-shapes) and with `\includegraphics` as in the example on pg 165, "15.5 Generalized Filling: Using Arbitrary Pictures to Fill a Path" of the manual. The trick is basically to calculate the size of the node, and apply that to the size of the included graphics This is the output:

[image: test21.png]

Notice that the bigger shape is somewhat erroneously clipped at the right edge; that can be fixed with uncommenting the manual displacement used in `\p3` in the code, but that is somewhat of a brute force approach. If anyone knows of a more proper way to achieve this, please post an answer.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{zzz/.style={
  %draw=red,
  path picture={%
  %\pgftext{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{custombordershape_tikz.pdf}};
  \path let
    \p1=(path picture bounding box.south west),
    \p2=(path picture bounding box.north east)
  in
    [draw=red] (\p1) -- (\p2)
    coordinate (nsz) at ($(\p2)-(\p1)-(2*\pgflinewidth,2*\pgflinewidth)$) ;
  \path let
    \p1=(nsz),
    \p2=(path picture bounding box.center),
    \p3=(\p2)
%     \p3=($(\p2)-(0.008*\x1,0)$)
  in
    node[anchor=center] at (\p3) {
      \includegraphics[width=\x1,height=\y1]{custombordershape_tikz.pdf}
    };
}}}
\node[zzz] (n1) at (1,0) {Testing};
\node[align=left,text width=250pt,minimum width=250pt,zzz] (n2) [right=5pt of n1] {\lipsum[4]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```