# Block Diagram drawing with Tikz - misplaced dot and other

Tags: vertical-alignment, tikz-styles, tikzsymbols

I am trying to generate this table:

[image]

I have two questions regarding the generation:

1. When I position the dot to try to match up row 3 on the block diagram, I get the dot being offset from the line like this:

   [image]

How do I get the dot to be vertically centered on the line?

2. How do I go about getting the summer symbol with the "X" and "+" sign like that shown in row 2?:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
    \usepackage{esint}
    \usepackage{blox}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}

    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    %======================================================================================
    %   FONTS
    %======================================================================================

    \usepackage{unicode-math}  % loads 'fontspec' automatically

    \setmainfont{Fira Sans Light}[
         Numbers       = OldStyle,
         BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
         ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
         BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
    \setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}[
         Numbers       = OldStyle,
         BoldFont      = Fira Sans Medium,
         ItalicFont    = Fira Sans Light Italic,
         BoldItalicFont= Fira Sans Medium Italic]
    % For source code
    \setmonofont{Source Code Pro Light}[
         BoldFont=Source Code Pro]

    %% Math font
    \setmathfont{Asana Math} % or some other suitable font


    \advance\topmargin-1in
    \advance\textheight3in
    \advance\textwidth3in
    \advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
    \advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
    \parindent0pt
    \parskip2pt
    \newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{multicols*}{3}

    \newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
    boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
      title=#2,colback=white}


        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz
    \tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=green!35, rectangle, scale=0.9,
        minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em},
    sum/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=0.2cm},
    input/.style={coordinate},
    output/.style={coordinate},
    pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}},
    dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt}}


    %------------ Block Diagrams ---------------
    \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{mybox}{Block Diagrams}
        \vspace*{0.1cm}
        \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} p{3cm} p{2cm}}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=0.5cm,>=latex']

                \node [input, name=input31] {};
                \node [block, right = 1cm of input31] (controller31) {$G$};
                \node [output, right = 0.5cm of controller31, name=output31] {};

                \draw [->] (input31) -- node[name=X31s] {$u$} (controller31);
                \draw [->] (input31) -- node[dot, pos=0.5] {} (controller31);
                \draw [->] (controller31) -- node[name=g31] {$y$} (output31);
                %\draw node at (1,-0.05) {\textbullet};

            \end{tikzpicture} &
                    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, remember picture,overlay, auto, node distance=.5cm,>=latex']

                \node [input, name=input2] {};
                \node [block, right = 0.5cm of input2] (controller3) {$G_{1}\pm G_{2}$};
                \node [output, right = 0.5cm of controller3, name=output2] {};

                \draw [->] (input2) -- node[name=$X2(s)$] {$X(s)$} (controller3);
                \draw [->] (controller3) -- node{$Y{s}$} (output2);
            \end{tikzpicture} &
            $Y=(G_{1}\pm G_{2})X$
            \end{tabular}
            \vspace*{1cm}

        \end{mybox}
    \end{minipage}

    \end{multicols*}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: please reduce your mwe to your problems, i.e. images which you show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one more answer ...

you have many issues with your code:

- your table with block diagrams are wider than your "myblock", even if i reduce page porders to 15mm and `\columnsep` to 1mm.
- `minipage` is not needed, width of `mybox` is determined by `multicols*`.
- dot in the first image in the third row you should draw as shape, not as node content.
- a solution for `sum` as you like to have you can find in [Marijn's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn) answer above, however this is unusual symbol for summation. i would rather use `+` inside circle as you can see in mwe below.
- code is unnecessary complicated (`overly` and `remember picture` are not needed), but to `tikzpicture` options should be added `baseline` for better vertical aligning of images in table.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[landscape
              margin=15mm]{geometry}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta,
                  calc,
                  decorations.pathmorphing,
                  positioning,
                  quotes,
                  shapes}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \setlength\columnsep{1mm}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=\linewidth,
      fontupper=\scriptsize,
      fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize,
      colbacktitle=black,
      enhanced,
      attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
      boxed title style={sharp corners},
      left=1pt, top=3pt, bottom=2pt, right=1pt,
      title=#2,
      colback=white}
  \usepackage{booktabs}

  \parindent0pt
  \parskip2pt

  \begin{document}

  \begin{multicols*}{3}

  \tikzset{
              > = Latex,
   block/.style = {draw, fill=green!35, minimum size=1em},
     sum/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=1pt},
     dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill=black, minimum size=3pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
  node distance = 4mm and 8mm
          }
  %------------ Block Diagrams ---------------
  %\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
      \begin{mybox}{Block Diagrams}
      \vspace*{0.1cm}
      \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
      \begin{tabular}{l l l}
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Block Diagrams}  &   \\
          \cmidrule{1-2}
      original    & equivalent    & equation  \\
          \midrule
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline]
      \coordinate (in);
      \node [block, right = of in]         (controller)   {$G_{1}$};
      \node [block, right = 4mm of controller] (controller2)  {$G_{2}$};
      \coordinate[right=of controller2]    (out);
      %
      \draw [->]  (in)            edge ["$X(s)$"] (controller)
                  (controller)    edge            (controller2)
                  (controller2)    to ["$Y{s}$"]  (out);
      \end{tikzpicture}
          &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline]
      \coordinate (in);
      \node [block, right = of in]        (controller3) {$G_{1}G_{2}$};
      \coordinate[right=of controller3]   (out);
      %
      \draw [->]  (in)            edge ["$X(s)$"] (controller3)
                  (controller3)    to  ["$Y{s}$"] (out);
      \end{tikzpicture}
              &   $Y=(G_{1}G_{2})X$       \\
          \midrule
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline]
      \coordinate (in);
      \node [block, right = of in]          (controller1) {$G_{1}$};
      \node [sum, right = 5mm of controller1] (sum) {$+$};
      \coordinate[right = of sum]   (out);
      \node [block, below = of controller1] (controller2) {$G_{2}$};
      %
      \draw [->]  (in)            edge ["$X(s)$"] (controller1)
                  (controller1)   edge            (sum)
                  (sum)           edge ["$Y{s}$"] (out)
                  ($(in)!0.5!(controller1.west)$) |- (controller2);
      \draw [->] (controller2) -|  node[below right, pos=1] {$\pm$} (sum);
      \end{tikzpicture}
          &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline]
      \coordinate (in);
      \node [block,  right = of in]        (controller) {$G_{1}\pm G_{2}$};
      \coordinate[right = of controller]   (out);
      %
      \draw [->]  (in)            edge ["$X(s)$"] (controller)
                  (controller)    to  ["$Y{s}$"] (out);
      \end{tikzpicture}
              &   $Y=(G_{1}\pm G_{2})X$   \\
          \midrule
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline]
      \coordinate (in);
      \node [dot, right = of in] (dot) {};
      \node [block, right = of dot]   (controller) {$G$};
      \coordinate[right = of controller]  (out1);
      \coordinate[below = of in]          (out2);
      %
      \draw [->]  (in)            edge ["$u$"]    (dot)
                  (dot)           edge            (controller)
                  (controller)    edge ["$y$"]    (out1)
                  (dot) |- node[above,pos=0.75] {$u$}  (out2);
      \end{tikzpicture}
          &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline]
      \coordinate (in);
      \node [block,  right = of in]         (controller) {$G_{1}\pm G_{2}$};
      \coordinate[right = of controller]   (out);
      %
      \draw [->]  (in)            edge ["$X(s)$"] (controller)
                  (controller)     to  ["$Y{s}$"] (out);
      \end{tikzpicture}
              &   $Y=(G_{1}\pm G_{2})X$   \\
      \end{tabular}
      \vspace*{1cm}
      \end{mybox}
  %\end{minipage}
  \end{multicols*}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: When I run your code the output is a bit different from the screenshot, the `dot` node is big (and has an invisible black _G_ in it) and the `sum` node is very small and does not have a `+` in it. Maybe you accidentally posted the wrong code?

Comment: @Marijn, ups,  it seems that i didn't upload last version of code.  corrected now. thank you for note.

Answer (score 1):

I make your code more minimal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes,arrows, arrows.meta, positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz
        \tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=green!35, rectangle, scale=0.9,
                minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em},
            sum/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=0.2cm},
            input/.style={coordinate},
            output/.style={coordinate},}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, auto, node distance=.5cm,>=latex'] % <----------------
        \node [input, name=input] {};
        \node [block, right = 0.5cm of input] (controller) {$G_{1}$};
        \node [sum, right = 0.5cm of controller] (sum) {};
        \node [block, below = 0.5cm of controller, node distance=0.9cm] (controller2) {$G_{2}$};
        \node [output, right = 0.5cm of sum, name=output] {};
        \draw [->] (input) -- node[name=Xs] {$X(s)$} (controller);
        \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=g1] {} (sum.west) node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=1.2pt,above,anchor=south east] {\tiny +}; % <----------------
        \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$Y{s}$} (output);
        \draw [->] (Xs) |- (controller2);
        \draw [->] (controller2) -| (sum.south) node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=1.2pt,right,anchor=north west] {\tiny\pm}; % <----------------
    \end{tikzpicture} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, auto, node distance=0.5cm,>=latex'] % <----------------
        \node [input, name=input31] {};
        \node [block, right = 1cm of input31] (controller31) {$G$};
        \node [output, right = 0.5cm of controller31, name=output31] {};
        %\draw [->] (input31) -- node[name=X31s] {$u$} (controller31);
        %\draw [->] (input31) -- node[dot, pos=0.5] {} (controller31);
        \draw [->] (input31) -- (controller31); % <----------------
        \fill [black] ($(input31.east)!.5!(controller31.west)$) circle [radius=.6mm] node [above] {$u$}; % <----------------
        \draw [->] (controller31) -- node[name=g31] {$y$} (output31);
        %\draw node at (1,-0.05) {\textbullet}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The crossed out circle can be produced with a `path picture` (see [TikZ Node with multiple shapes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47263/tikz-node-with-multiple-shapes)). This also allows to put a `+` in the node, although the size and positioning are done manually so this might not scale. The center dot in the second diagram can be produced with `anchor=center`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175969/block-diagrams-using-tikz
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=green!35, rectangle, scale=0.9,
    minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em},
sum/.style={draw, circle, node distance=0.2cm,path picture={%
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47263/tikz-node-with-multiple-shapes
\draw[black]
       (path picture bounding box.north west) -- (path picture bounding box.south east) 
       (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
       \node[xshift=-5pt] at (path picture bounding box.west) {\scalebox{.4}{+}};
      }},
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}},
dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=center}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=1}, auto, node distance=.5cm,>=latex']
   \node [input, name=input] {};
   \node [block, right = 0.5cm of input] (controller) {$G_{1}$};
   \node [sum, right = 0.5cm of controller] (sum) {};
   \node [block, below = 0.5cm of controller, node distance=0.9cm] (controller2) {$G_{2}$};
   \node [output, right = 0.5cm of sum, name=output] {};

   \draw [->] (input) -- node[name=Xs] {$X(s)$} (controller);
   \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=g1] {} (sum);
   \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$Y{s}$} (output);
   \draw [->] (Xs) |- (controller2);
   \draw [->] (controller2) -| (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]