# Place textbox within minipage at specific location with line break

Tags: floats, minipage

I am attempting to place some text/equations/table within a minibox next to a figure.  I was following the [example solution given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24663/how-to-place-a-floating-text-box-at-a-specified-location-in-page-coordinates).  When I try to do a page break I get a compile error.  This is what I get with the current code:

[image]

I would like to fit the equations within the red box via a page break or any other means.

Is there a simpler solution available?

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, quotes, decorations.pathmorphing, shapes, arrows.meta, positioning, calc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%======================================================================================
%   FOR TEXTBOX
%======================================================================================
\usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}
\newcommand{\placetextbox}[3]{% \placetextbox{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
  \setbox0=\hbox{#3}% Put <stuff> in a box
    \AddToShipoutPictureFG*
    {\put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\makebox[0pt][c]{\begin{tabular}{l}#3\end{tabular}}}}
  }%

\advance\topmargin-1in
\advance\textheight3in
\advance\textwidth3in
\advance\oddsidemargin-1.5in
\advance\evensidemargin-1.5in
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=0.97\textwidth,fontupper=\scriptsize,
fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize, colbacktitle=black,enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
boxed title style={sharp corners},top=3pt,bottom=2pt,
  title=#2,colback=white}


%-------------------SECOND ORDER SYSTEM-----------------------------------

\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
    \begin{mybox}{Second Order System}
$\dfrac{C(s)}{R(s)} =\dfrac{\omega^{2}_{n}}{s^{2}+2\zeta\omega_{n}s+\omega^{2}_{n}},$
$\omega_{n}=$ natural frequency, $\zeta=$ damping coefficient(ratio).
\hspace*{6cm}$s_{1,2}=-\zeta\omega_{n}\pm\omega_{n}\sqrt{\zeta^{2}-1}$
\vspace*{-0.4cm}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=3cm]{example-image-b} 
\end{flushleft}
\end{figure}

\placetextbox{0.4}{.9}{
\scriptsize{
Step Response: $C(s) =\dfrac{\omega^{2}_{n}}{s(s^{2}+2\zeta\omega_{n}s+\omega^{2}_{n})},$
$c(t)=1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}}e^{-\zeta\omega_{n}t}\cos\left(\omega_{n}\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}t-\tan^{-1}\left(\zeta/\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}\right)\right)$}}

    \end{mybox}
\end{minipage}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how is this question related to your https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455775/block-diagram-drawing-with-tikz-misplaced-dot-and-other? there, as i can judge, you have solution. just adapt table to your need.

Comment: When I put a line break, say for example I use this code, `Step Response: \\$C(s) =\dfrac{\omega^{2}_{n}}{s(s^{2}+2\zeta\omega_{n}s+\omega^{2}_{n})},$\\,' I get the error `Missing } inserted...l.371  \end{multicols*}`  How can I break up the lines without the error?

Comment: if you like to have multi line math expressions, than you need to use appropriate math environments defined `amsmath`, `mathtools`, `nccmath` or other packages. for start search for example of use  `gather`, `align` environments or questions tagged with `amsmath` or `mathtools`.

Comment: and please, reduce your document example to a mwe,  for example on base of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455775/block-diagram-drawing-with-tikz-misplaced-dot-and-other/455792#455792 ...

Comment: @Zarko, are you suggesting that I put the images, text in a table?  If that is the case, there will be a lot of wasted space.  I need to fill up as much white space that I can.  Thanks!

Comment: @Zarko, the attached code does have most of the environments that you mentioned.  How come the `\\` does not work for me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i correct understood you ... than the best what i can manages from your code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,
            margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{1mm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{text width=\linewidth,
    fontupper=\scriptsize,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize,
    colbacktitle=black,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=3mm},
    boxed title style={sharp corners},
    left=1pt, top=3pt, bottom=2pt, right=1pt,
    title=#2,
    colback=white}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}        % <--- new
\usepackage{mathtools}              % <--- new
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}      % <--- new
\parindent0pt
\parskip2pt

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}
    \begin{mybox}{Second Order System}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c >{$}l<$}
\includegraphics[width=39mm, valign=c]{example-image-b}
    &   \begin{aligned}
        \dfrac{C(s)}{R(s)}
             & = \dfrac{\omega^{2}_{n}}{s^{2}+2\zeta\omega_{n}s+\omega^{2}_{n}},    \\
        \omega_{n}
             &{:}\; \text{natural frequency},                                          \\
        \zeta
             &{:}\; \text{damping coefficient (ratio).}                                \\
        s_{1,2}
             & =- \zeta\omega_{n}\pm\omega_{n}\sqrt{\zeta^{2}-1}                    \\[1ex]
             &   \text{Step Response:}                                               \\
        C(s) & = \dfrac{\omega^{2}_{n}}
                       {s(s^{2}+2\zeta\omega_{n}s+\omega^{2}_{n})},                 \\
        c(t) & = \begin{multlined}[t]
                    1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}} e^{-\zeta\omega_{n}t}   \\[-2ex]
                    \cos\Bigl[\omega_{n} \sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}t                \\
                    -\tan^{-1}\Bigl(\zeta/\sqrt{1-\zeta^{2}}\Bigr)\Bigr]
                    \end{multlined}
            \end{aligned}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{mybox}

\end{multicols*}
```

which gives:

[image]

code in above mwe is based on  [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455775/block-diagram-drawing-with-tikz-misplaced-dot-and-other/455792#455792) to one of yours previous question. to it are added few new packages (indicated by `% <--- new`).